# Python len() not good

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file and i want to get the lines' length.

But when i get the length:

> 8 10 11 9 9 30 11 12 11 10 10 8 8 26 13 etc...

There is my code:

```
competition = []
with open('verseny.txt') as f:
    competitor_number= int(next(f))
    for line in f:
        shots = line.split()
        competition.append(str(shots))

for num,shots in enumerate(competition, 1):
    if '++' in shots:
        print(num, end=",")

print("\n")

for shots in competition:
    print(len(shots))
```

The contents of `verseny.txt` is:

```
21
+--+
--+++-
-+--+--
++---
-++--
--+-+++----------------+-+
+-++--+
-+-+++-+
-+--+-+
--+++-
-+--+-
++--
-+--
-++----------------+-+
+-++-+--+
-+-+++-
-+--+-+-
++---+
-++-+-
--+-+++---+-------------+-+
+-++--+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `str(line.split())` you're essentially turning `"+--+\n"` into `"['+--+']"` (which has a length of `8`).

Instead of `line.split()` you probably meant to use `line.strip()`.

Comment: This is the solution! :D Thanks!

Comment: or `line.rstrip()` to remove only to the right.

Comment: @Giton22 if that's the solution, just accept the answer.

Comment: i can't accept it yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Length of each lines appended in a list 
l=[]
for f in open('verseny.txt'):
    l.append(len(f))

print l



#if you want number of line in this file
count=-1
for f in open('verseny.txt'):
    count+=1
print count
```